# Open only one activity, without the main activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an application that has one service and 2 activities.One activity (the main one) is a preferences activity and the other one is a dialog themed activity. The service from time to time needs to open only the dialog themed activity (using FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).
The problem is that when the preferences activity is opened in background (for example the user pressed HOME key instead of BACK, so the activity is OnPause) and the service tries to open the dialog themed activity, also the main activity is opened (comes in foreground).
I don't want this. So, how can I open only the themed activity from the service, without the main activity pop up ?

Android Manifest .xml

```
    <service android:name=".SimpleService"> </service>
<activity
    android:name=".Preferences" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>       
    </activity>

           <activity android:name=".popup_activity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" android:label="@string/app_name">                  
           <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.SAMPLE_CODE" />
           </intent-filter>
           <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="screenon.popup.activity" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           </intent-filter>           
            </activity>
```

And from the service :

```
           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
               intent.addCategory("screenon.popup.activity");
               intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

               startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea. Don't open windows without user intervention

Comment: This is another problem, let forget about the service and let's say that the dialog themed activity is opened from another activity. The problem remains

Comment: Going to need to see some code... pleas post the <activity> tags from your AndroidManifest.xml and the activity-launching code from your service.

Comment: I'll post the code, but this is not a particular situation, you can replicate it quite easy by creating an application with 2 activities and then trying to open (from a service or another application) just the the second one without the MAIN one. If previous of trying this your MAIN activity is opened in background, then trying to open the second one will also open your main activity.

Comment: I found a workaround described [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282204/android-open-dialogue-activity-without-opening-main-activity-behind-it/18136977#18136977

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex , I believe that all you want is to display preferences activity just once & then it must die(or lets say finish()) .

In that case you can override onResume of the preferences activity
to finish your preferences activity after it is resumed after pause

```
@Override
    public void onResume()
{
   //if activity is resumed after onPause then only run it 
  this.finish();  //simply kill your activity if it is resumed after pause
}
```

**EDIT**-To know whether the activity was paused you need to override onPause().I think you can dig out the rest.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for the [android:launchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) attribute.